# Gradle task is not running

Tags: android, groovy, gradle, android-studio

I'm finally learning Android development after doing iOS for awhile. I'll not have a lot of terminology down, so please be kind.

After initially creating my own sqlite file (via a SQLiteOpenHelper subclass) and attempting to handle all the persisted data model stuff myself, I've decided to opt for some third party code to handle it all. The Android engineers in my company suggested GreenDAO.

In order to create the models and DAO objects (and I think the sqlite file too) I was also directed towards setting up some gradle build scripts. This is where I think I have some things wrong.

I'm using Android Studio and the pertinent parts of my project structure looks like this...

```
- Project Directory
    - app
        - build.gradle
    - buildSrc
        - src/main/groovy/com/ridinghorses/app
            - DatabaseBuilder.groovy
        - build.gradle
    - build.gradle
```

In my project directory's build.gradle

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

In my buildSrc directory's build.gradle...

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compile 'de.greenrobot:greendao-generator:1.3.+@jar'
    compile 'org.freemarker:freemarker:2.3.+'
}
```

In my app directory's build.gradle

```
apply plugin: 'android'

import com.ridinghorses.app.DatabaseBuilder;

android {
    compileSdkVersion 19
    buildToolsVersion "19.0.3"

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 8
        targetSdkVersion 19
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:19.+'
}

task buildDatabase {
    inputs.file file('../buildSrc/src/main/groovy/com/ridinghorses/app/DatabaseBuilder.groovy')
    outputs.dir file('src/main/java/com/ridinghorses/app/database/dao')

    doLast {
        println('Calling DatabaseBuilder::buildDatabase')
        new DatabaseBuilder().buildDatabase(file('src/main/java/').path)
    }
}
```

Finally in my DatabaseBuilder.groovy file

```
package com.ridinghorses.app
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoGenerator
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.DaoUtil
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Entity
import de.greenrobot.daogenerator.Schema

public class DatabaseBuilder {
    // tables
    private Entity tier
    private Entity lesson

    def buildDatabase(String outPath) {

        println("DatabaseBuilder::buildDatabase")

        def schema = new Schema(1, "com.ridinghorses.app.database.dao")

        tier = schema.addEntity('Tier')
        lesson = schema.addEntity('Lesson')

        buildTierTable()
        buildLessonTable()

        def generator = new DaoGenerator()
        generator.generateAll(schema, outPath)
    }

    private buildTierTable() {
        tier.addIdProperty()
                .primaryKey()
        addStringProperty(tier, 'title')
                .notNull()
                .index()

    }

    private buildLessonTable() {
        lesson.addIdProperty()
                .primaryKey()
        addStringProperty(lesson, 'title')

        def tierId = addLongProperty(lesson, 'tierId').getProperty()
        lesson.addToOne(tier, tierId)
    }
}
```

With all this done I sync my project with gradle files and build. I never see any of the println statements in either Android Studio's Console or Logcat and I never see any of my models generated. I also never receive any errors saying something I did was wrong.

If I purposefully put in a syntax error, the build process stops and I get an error message. So that tells me it's at least trying to do something with the files I have generated. But I'm not sure what to try next. You cannot set breakpoints. Well you can set them, they just won't get hit.

Comment: You'll need to explicitly run the `buildDatabase` task, or make other task(s) depend on it.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, ah, ok. All the docs show how to invoke a task from command line ie `gradle -q buildDatabase`, but where/how would that work from a build.gradle script? I've tried `buildDatabase()`, which is where I run out of ideas. Thanks!

Comment: You can't call a task from a build script, but you can make another task depend on it. I don't know if/which tasks get executed when importing into Android Studio, but probably IDE import isn't the right point in time for running `buildDatabase` anyway.

Comment: @PeterNiederwieser, I think it's what the greenDAO example code suggests. They  've been reading through the docs and